# How do I dismiss an autocomplete suggestion in Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

When I'm writing Docstrings in Python3, I'm ending all of my sentences with periods and I see an autocomplete suggestion like this:

[image]

In this case it wants to replace the string "wager." with "wagerself."

If I press `Enter` or `Tab` the string replaces. I've messed around with all the logical buttons (Including adding an extra space which doesn't work), and nothing will allow me on my merry way to a newline.

This problem occurs both with and without the autocomplete-python package installed.

I do want to use auto-complete when I type a dot after an object, just not in the comments.

Is there a way to either:

1. Dismiss the autocomplete suggestion as they come up.

-- or --

2. Change the autocomplete to be aware of the context, i.e. not autocomplete dots when I'm in a string/comment.

Answer (score 1):

From experimenting with different key combos, `ctrl + enter` will ignore the suggestion and allow you to go to the next line without altering what you've typed.

I haven't found any documentation around this, so I'm not sure if there's a similar key combo for `tab` or not. I couldn't find anything myself beyond `alt + tab`ing to lose focus, which causes the suggestion to go away, then `alt + tab`ing back to hit tab, which obviously isn't ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Atom 1.44.0 on Windows and have found that `shift + enter` works to dismiss an autocomplete suggestion. No luck with tab on this platform though.

Comment: Could you be more specific with your question, please?

Comment: @B--rian Sure, it's a typo. :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jason! I guess [tiser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/700015/tiser) meant to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

I use atom extensively, and have found that a quick left-right cursor move will leave the typed text in place and will NOT reactivate the suggestion list, unless more characters are typed. You can then type  and move on to the next line.

I was actually searching myself for a way to exclude "then" from the autocomplete action, because I have text in other locations that has it as a commented "Then".  I was hoping to find a way to exclude that word completely, but thought to share my work-around for that little bit, instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem where my text is getting replaced with cached words where if I wanted to type “manage” but if I have used “management “ before, I will get the text what I don’t want if I press enter. I went into preferences and followed the same steps mentioned in the below article and once the preferences are changed, I don’t see the word suggestions anymore. I felt so relieved.
https://elearning.wsldp.com/pcmagazine/disable-code-hints-atom-editor/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).